# Add a column to an existing dataframe with random fixed values in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I'm new to Pyspark and I'm trying to add a new column to my existing dataframe. The new column should contain only 4 fixed values (e.g. `1,2,3,4`) and I'd like to randomly pick one of the values for each row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyspark dataframes are immutable, so you have to return a new one (e.g. you can't just assign to it the way you can with Pandas dataframes).  To do what you want use a `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import numpy as np

df = <original df>

udf_randint = udf(np.random.randint(1, 4))
df_new = df.withColumn("random_num": udf_randint)
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to call `lit` on the numpy list.  That's what happens when I try to answer questions without Spark in front of you.  I'll edit it.

Comment: may I ask what the last argument (size) is for? I tried without that argument and it gives me the same value all the time, instead of being random. it was 3 all the time

Comment: Size literally tells numpy how many random values you want.  So if you leave it off it's just a single random integer by default.  If you set it to `size=2` then it returns an array with two random integers in it, etc.

Comment: got it. but for some reason when I set it it gives me error. here is the error message. AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Comment: Sounds like a missing close parentheses maybe?

Comment: After more contemplation I think I was wrong in the first place and you'll need to use a `udf`.  Updated the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the error: : invalid syntax becasue of the : in ("random_num": udf_randint). Can you help @jeff

Comment: df.withColumn("random_num": udf_randint). It looks that syntax is not valid aynmore in PySpark @LN_P